# How to concatenate a string to values inside a nested array in powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powercli

I have a nested array `@(@('1','3'), @('5','7','9'), @('2','4','6'))`

```
$podnumbers = (3,2,2)
$buffer = 0
$podNarr = foreach ($pd in $podnumbers) {
    $podNarr1 = for($i=0;$i -lt $pd;$i = $i+1) {
      Read-Host -Prompt "Assign the pod numbers"
    }
    ,$podNarr1
    $buffer = $buffer + 1
   }

$podNarr | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host Object type: $_.gettype().BaseType.name
    Write-Host Member count: $_.count
    Write-Host Values: $_
}
```

Here is the output for the above block:

```
Object type: Array
Member count: 2
Values: 1 3
Object type: Array
Member count: 3
Values: 2 4 6
Object type: Array
Member count: 3
Values: 5 7 9
```

I'm trying to concatenate **Port Group-** to the values in a nested array using the below code

```
$port = "Port Group-"
$portarr = $podNarr | ForEach-Object {
      $port + $_
    }
Write-Output `n
$portarr | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host Values: $_
}
```

Above code produces the output as:

```
Values: Port Group-1 3
Values: Port Group-2 4 6
Values: Port Group-5 7 9
```

I wanted the output as, **@(@('Port Group-1','Port Group-3'), @('Port Group-5','Port Group-7','Port Group-9'), @('Port Group-2','Port Group-4','Port Group-6'))**

```
Values: Port Group-1 Port Group-3
Values: Port Group-2 Port Group-4 Port Group-6
Values: Port Group-5 Port Group-7 Port Group-9
```

How to fulfill my objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have such a proposal

```
@(@('1','3'), @('5','7','9'), @('2','4','6')) | foreach{
"Values: " + ($_|foreach{"Port Group-$_"})  
}
```

output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need two for loops. One loops through the outer array and the latter through nested arrays. A foreach won't do, as iterating and changing an array are mutually exclusive operations.

```
$arr = @(@('1','3'), @('5','7','9'), @('2','4','6'))

# Here we traverse through the outer elements
for($a = 0; $a -lt $arr.length; ++$a) {

    # Process each nested array and update its value    
    for($b = 0; $b -lt $arr[$a].length; ++$b) {
        $arr[$a][$b] =  $("Port group-{0} "-f $arr[$a][$b])
    }
}

# Output
$arr | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host Object type: $_.gettype().BaseType.name
    Write-Host Member count: $_.count
    Write-Host Values: $_
}

Object type: Array
Member count: 2
Values: Port group-1  Port group-3
Object type: Array
Member count: 3
Values: Port group-5  Port group-7  Port group-9
Object type: Array
Member count: 3
Values: Port group-2  Port group-4  Port group-6
```

Answer (score 1):

Powershell unwraps arrays if you don't force output to become an array.
You can force this by prepending it with a unary comma that wraps the array inside another 1-element array. When that part gets unwrapped, the original array is preserved.

Something like

```
$a = @(@('1','3'), @('5','7','9'), @('2','4','6'))
$b = $a | ForEach-Object {
    $c = foreach ($port in $_) { 'Port Group-{0}' -f $port }
    # output this array as ARRAY by wrapping it in a 1-element new array using the unary comma
    ,$c
}


Write-Host $b[0]
Write-Host $b[1]
Write-Host $b[2]
```

Output

```
Port Group-1 Port Group-3
Port Group-5 Port Group-7 Port Group-9
Port Group-2 Port Group-4 Port Group-6
```

Comment: @DjangoUnchained The `-f` [Format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#format-operator--f) replaces numbered placeholders in a template string to format a new string. The placeholders take the form of `{0}`, `{1}` etc. In this case, it fills in the `$port`value in template string `'Port Group-{0}'` where the `{0}` is. You can do a lot more with this, have a lok at the link in this comment.